# Water distiller reset button malfunction?

Tags: repair

I have a countertop water distiller ( brand: Waterwise, model: 4000 ) with a reset button that has to be pressed for the distiller to start working when it has been refilled with water.

While the distiller is working, the reset button is loose.

Once refilled with water and the power cord plugged back in, the reset button can be pressed ( once only, then it gets loose ), which start the distiller, and so on.

Since a whuke, the reset button stays loose, which gives me the impression that the button itself is broken. I don't understand how a reset switch works, so I cannot determine if I have to replace this button or if it might be keeping its loose position because another part of the distiller is defective.

Thank you for your help, guidance and for your advices.

Comment: what do you mean by  `loose`?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We aren't going to be able to help you; you should [contact the company's support line](https://www.waterwise.com/contact-us) for this. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about small appliance repair.

Comment: I changed the category. I will precise my post according to your remarks in a moment. Thank you.

Comment: By loose, I mean that when working normally, if you pressed it while the distillation process, it was like pushing on a button w/o spring to push it back to its original state. There was no 'click', it just would let itself hit the end of its course without doing anything. When some sensor detects that the distiller is empty and has to stop, the appliance would shut down. After disconnecting from the plug, opened, refilled and powerplug put back on, the button would again be possible to actually clic'ed, which would start the ebullition again. Until next refill, the button would be loose.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the Waterwise 4000 specs and available replacement parts I would not worry about it if it is properly running its 4 hour cycle. If it is not properly functioning then yes replace it but your observation of loose verses tight don’t match what I see on the parts list, So if it ain’t broke don’t fix it.